# Как разобрать строку, передаваемую в консоль, на массив чаров

Tags: c

Попробовал следующий код, но программа завершается, так и не выдав результата.

```
char string[6];
    scanf_s("%c", string);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(string) / sizeof(string[0]); i++) {
        printf("%c", string[i]);
    }
```

Как можно в разобрать строку из консоли на массив чаров?

Answer (score 2):

Ваше

```
scanf_s("%c", string);
```

читает *один символ*. Для чтения *слова* надо писать

```
scanf_s("%s", string,6);
```

А строку, если она не из одного слова, лучше читать через `gets_s`

```
gets_s(string,6);
```

или как

```
scanf_s("%[^\n]",string,6);
```

P.S. Надеюсь, о том, что строка в С заканчивается нулевым символом, вы помните?

Comment: Да, спасибо, сработало! Но как сделать так, чтобы размер массива менялся в зависимости от размера слова?

Comment: Замечу вскользь, что об этом в вашем вопросе не говорится ни слова... Но массив использовать динамический, через `malloc`, читать по одному символу и наращивать массив через `realloc`. Чтобы не наращивать по одному символу (неэффективно), можно помнить размер выделенной памяти и сколько там уже записано, и при исчерпании памяти добавлять сразу блоками (эффективнее всего увеличивать память сразу, скажем, в 2 раза).